# SharePoint search with special characters not working

Tags: search, sharepoint-on-prem

I am using list "Find an item" search. I have created the managed property and enabled "Search" and performed full crawl. The field type is single line of text.
I have value 555;666 and search with the whole text "555;666" is not working no matter what KQL operator or combination used.
Doesn't search work if there are any special characters in between two numbers and stored as text?

Some of the attempts
555;666 - no results
555* - no results
*666 - no results

This issue is on SharePoint 2013 on premises environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both "," and ";" are used in SharePoint as delimiters.

- Is your column a multi-valued Choice or other column?
- In your SharePoint installation, is the list separator a "," or a
  ";"?

In a Single Line of Text column test that I just did, the semicolon is behaving as a delimiter wildcard. It finds ",", ";", " " and other word delimiters, and is behaving as an AND.

Searching for `555;777` finds:

```
555,777
555 777
555;777
```

and, searching for `777;555` finds the same items:

```
555,777
555 777
555;777
```

I'm going to do some more test and post back what I find.

---

After some more testing, I'm guessing that your column is a checkboxed Choice column (or other multi-select column). The semicolon is the default delimiter used to separate the selections and is not part of the data.

I could not duplicate your issue with a Single Line of text column that used a semicolon in the text. But, I did discover an interesting search feature... The semicolon serves as an AND for multiple words in the same field!

[image]

When searching for two words, and only one exists, no items are returned.

[image]

Comment: interesting.. my value is  41090;630130 in Single Line of text column and  when I searched with any of these values (two words or one word) 41090;630130, 41090, 630130.. no items are returned in any case.

Comment: What is your default delimiter in SharePoint? A comma or a semicolon? It varies buy country / culture. For example, when you write a formula for a calculated column, do you write IF(  ,  ,  ) or IF(  ;  ;  ).

Answer (score 0):

> > Have you tried with above given value? Is it working for you?

**Using this data:**

[image]

**I got these results:**

[image]

Comment: The Locale is set to Germany (In Regional Settings) and default language is set English and alternate language is set to Germany. Does this have any impact?

Comment: Pretty sure that does impact both search and  Calculated columns. At what level is this? User, site, farm?